# Defining mathematical functions with summation in Octave

Tags: octave

I want to define the  mathematical function sum(x^z)+z  where x ranges from 1:10 and z is a variable

One way I tried is

```
syms z
f=@(z)(z)
for i=1:10
    f=f+(i.^z)
end
```

But this leads to a error:   binary operator '+' not implemented for 'function handle' by 'matrix' operations

I also tried to define a function initially of two variables x and z as

```
syms x
syms z
f(x,z)=z+(x.^z)
sum(f([1:10,z]))
```

It also gives error

Please tell me the correct method to do this.

Comment: `f = @(z) sum ((1:10) .^z) + z; ` which you can then call like `f(5)`

Comment: Thanks ...it works

Comment: @DivyatMahajan Slow down and look at his example carefully. You've basically written it out already yourself and his solution is easily adaptabe to your question: `f = @(z) sum ( ((1:10) .^z) .* log(1:10) );`

Comment: You're not going to ask a question about every single series you want to sum...are you?